# removing word from array string using .split() and .filter() methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter, split

I am attempting to build a small app that allows the user to input a string into an array, split the string into individual array items, and then (in a separate field) input the specific word from the string desired to be filtered. The current setup enables the user to input one long string such as "this is a new string", while clicking "add string" results in the string being split ("this,is,a,new,string"). However, upon inputting one of these words into the filtering field (ex. "new"), the filter function appears to still return the enter post-split array, without filtering out the desired word. Any thoughts on how to fix this so that an inputted word chosen from the original string is filtered? Thanks!

JS:

```
var array = [];

function addStr() {
  var str = document.getElementById("newInput").value;
  var addArray = str.split(" ");
  array.push(addArray);
  document.getElementById("main").append(addArray);
  document.getElementById("newInput").value = "";
}

function addFilterWord() {
  var newText = document.getElementById("wordFilter").value;
  array.push(newText);
  document.getElementById("filter").append(newText);
  document.getElementById("wordFilter").value = "";
  const arrayUpdate = array.filter(param => {
  return param != newText;
});

document.getElementById("final").append(arrayUpdate);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="newInput">
<button onclick="addStr()">Add String</button>

<input id="wordFilter">
<button onclick="addFilterWord()">Filter Word</button>

<p id="main"></p>
<p id="filter"></p>
<p id="final"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution

```js
var addArray = [];

const newInput = document.getElementById("newInput");
const wordFilter = document.getElementById("wordFilter");

const filter =   document.getElementById("filter");
const final = document.getElementById("final");
const main = document.getElementById("main");

function addStr() {
  var str = newInput.value;
  addArray = addArray.concat(str.trim().split(" "));
  newInput.value = "";
  main.innerText = "Main: " + addArray.join(", ");
}

function addFilterWord() {
  var newText = wordFilter.value;
  filter.innerText = "Filter: " + newText;
  final.innerText = "Final: " +  addArray.filter(item=>item.includes(newText)).join(", ");
};
```

```html
<input id="newInput">
<button onclick="addStr()">Add String</button>

<input id="wordFilter">
<button onclick="addFilterWord()">Filter Word</button>

<p id="main"></p>
<p id="filter"></p>
<p id="final"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This mostly worked, but I ended up replacing your final.innerText line with "final.innerText = "Final: " +  addArray.filter(param => {return param != newText;}).join(" ");" and that enabled the app to do what was intended, so thank you for helping me get on the right track. Could you clarify how you knew to implement .concat() and .trim() methods to make this work? Appreciated!

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 , since you needed to add each word to addArray, I either had a choice of looping through each word and then pushing it to addArray, or simply I could merge both of them and update addArray. I obviously chose the ladder and used concat to merge both of them. As for trim, the user can always accidentally add some unwanted space.

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 don't forget to upvote and mark as the right answer if this helped you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again. I was experimenting a little more with your setup. Another question though.. is "addArray = str.split(" ");" the same thing as "addArray = addArray.concat(str.trim().split(" "));"? Meaning would "addArray = str.split(" ");" also constitute as "updating" addArray?

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 no, `addArray = str.split(" ");` means that you're replacing any previous words added with the new set in your input. With concat, you're keeping any previously added word while adding the new words. While I'm using the word "updated", it is not technically updating, I'm simply merging two arrays together and creating a new one, and replacing addArray with the new one. So in your example, you're replacing your old addArray with str.split(" ") array.

Comment: If you wish to refrain from replacing it you could as @MarkMeyer pointed out `addArray.push(...str.trim().split(" "))`, where this would be a "true" update.

Answer (score 1):

When you push an array into an array you end up with an array with one element, which is the array you pushed. For example:

```js
let str  = "this is a new string"
let array = []
var addArray = str.split(" ");
array.push(addArray);

// array has one element
console.log("length:", array.length)
console.log(array)
```

You can instead spread one array into the other:

```js
let str  = "this is a new string"
let array = []
var addArray = str.split(" ");
array.push(...addArray);
// now array has all the elments on the first level
console.log("length:", array.length)
console.log(array)
```

There are other options is the spread operator isn't possible (like with old browsers). You can use [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) but you'll then be making a new array so you'll need to change a few things.

Answer (score 0):

replace line no. 6  with  `array.push(...addArray);`

comment line no. 13 `//array.push(newText);`

and it should work as intended :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This appears to work. Could you perhaps clarify how implementing the spread syntax in the push method solved the issue? Appreciated!